# Cannot compare a variable with datatable values - C#

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable

I'm comparing a variable with some values kept in a datatable from a database.

However, I can't get the value from the rows in the datatable to compare with a variable.

My code is the following:

```
private void tabelacategorias_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var idtabelacat = tabelacategorias.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id_categoria"].Value;

        MySqlConnection mConn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;server = localhost; port=3307; database = startselling; user = root; password = usbw;");
        MySqlCommand command_getcats = new MySqlCommand("SELECT c.id_categoria FROM produtos p RIGHT JOIN categorias c ON p.id_categoria = c.id_categoria WHERE p.id_categoria IS NULL", mConn);
        DataTable dtcats = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter dacats = new MySqlDataAdapter(command_getcats);
        mConn.Open();
        dacats.Fill(dtcats);
        mConn.Close();
        numcats = dtcats.Rows.Count;
        int v = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dtcats.Rows)
        {
            var idcats = row["c.id_categoria"];    

            if (idcats == idtabelacat)
            {
                MySqlCommand command_delcat = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM categorias where id_categoria ='" + idtabelacat + "'");
                command_delcat.Connection = mConn;
                mConn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader reader = command_delcat.ExecuteReader();
                mConn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("You deleted the category!");
                v = 1;
                update_tabelas();                        
                break;

            }
        }
        if (v == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You aren't able to delete this category!");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the variable **idcats** return nothing. I want it to return a value from the datatable.

If you could help me, I'd be grateful!

Comment: use  `row["id_categoria"]`

Comment: Already tried...still doesn't work

Comment: Well, surely you don't use _c.id_categoria_ because this will trigger an ArgumentException

Comment: Already tried with **var idcats = row["id_categoria"];** and still don't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The columns returned from the query will not have the table alias, so use:
   row["id_categoria"]
2. `SELECT c.id_categoria FROM produtos p RIGHT JOIN categorias c ON p.id_categoria = c.id_categoria WHERE p.id_categoria IS NULL` means that **p.id_categoria IS NULL**, so it's logical that the variable will be null.

Change the `WHERE` clause in the query and the correct values will show in tha variable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helped! However when comparing in the IF clause, it acts like the values are different. I have 4 values from the database, and one of them is the same as the value compared. So, supposedly, when compared these two values, it enters the if clause. And it doesn't enter.

Comment: Debug the code and put a breakpoint on the IF clause. Then use the quick-watch and see what type is `idtabelacat ` and what type is `idcats`. Often database wrappers use nullable types.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry but I never used it before.

Comment: Ok. Let's take it one step at a time. Are you using Visual Studio ? If yes, what version ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Get the cursor to the IF clause. Press F9. A red dot appears on the left side of the editor. Now Press F5 or press the START button from the toolbar.

Now the code will run in debug mode.
It will stop when it reaches the breakpoint. When it does, you will be redirected to VS. Now right click on the first variable and select Inspect or Quick Watch. Do the same for the second variable. 
In a tool window below the editor the current value and type will appear for each variable.

Make sure they match.

Comment: Ok! So they doesn't match. However the first variable get more than one value. When it stops at the breakpoint, one variable is 4 and the other is 12, but the variable who gets the value from the datatable changes, from 4 to 8, and from 8 to 12. So, when the variable get the value 12, it will be equal to the other variable with the value 12, and then it supposedly enters the If clause.

Comment: Watch how many times is your method being called because you mapped an event on the grid. And generally grids tend to have a lot of events going on at one time. But I hope your original question was answered.

Comment: I think it is called only one time. My problem now is that when the 2 variables are equal, it doesn't act like it, it acts like they are always different.

Comment: Check the types also.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0UsguTsdfErRFFhTHJaUE04STg?usp=sharing) is my project if you want to take a look.

Comment: Without having more code to understand better the situation I'm afraid I cannot help you beyond this point.

Comment: All the code necessary to make this work is here, but if you can't, thanks anyway :) I apreciatte the help given!

Comment: It's working! I simply converted the variables into int! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to see you managed to get it done. Please mark the answer and / or comments you considered to had helped as useful or as a solution if you like.